# How to get an element within an attribute using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get the value of an element that is under an 2 attributes and then under another element.

```
<Setup>
        <Devices>
            <SampleRate>20000</SampleRate>
            <Device Type="AI">
                <Slot Index="0">
                   <OutputChannel>
                    <MeasuredQuantity>VOLTAGE</MeasuredQuantity>
                    <DualCore>True</DualCore>
                   </OutputChannel
                </Slot>
                <Slot Index="1">
                </Slot>
                <Slot Index="2">
                    <OutputChannel>
                    <MeasuredQuantity>VOLTAGE</MeasuredQuantity>
                    <DualCore>True</DualCore>
                   </OutputChannel
                </Slot>
            </Device>
        </Devices>
</Setup>
```

How would I go about getting the measured value?

```
string typeGage = setupFile.Root.Descendants("DewesoftSetup").Descendants("Devices")
                                .Where(w => w.Element("Device").Attribute("Type").Value == "AI")
                                .Where(w => w.Element("Slot").Attribute("Index").Value == i.ToString())
                                .Select(w => w.Element("MeasuredValue").Value)
                                .Single();
```

This throws an exception (I am guessing I cant use "Where" twice)

**UPDATE**

```
      for (int i = 0; i < Form1.app.Data.AllChannels.Count; i++)
      {
         found = false;
         IChannel ch = Form1.app.Data.AllChannels[i];

         if (ch.Used == true)
         {
            for (int row = 24; row <= 43; row++)
            {
               if (oSheetLocal.Cells[row, 2].Value == null)
               {
                  string typeGage = setupFile.Root.Descendants("Setup").Descendants("Devices")
                                   .Where(w => w.Element("Device").Attribute("Type").Value == "AI" &&
                                          w.Element("Device").Element("Slot").Attribute("Index").Value == i.ToString())
                                   .Select(w => w.Element("Device").Element("Slot").Element("OutputChannel").Element("MeasuredQuantity").Value)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();
}}}}
```

It works great the first run through but I try to get index 2 it returns null.

Comment: You'll need to decide how you want the results; do you want an object with, e.g., `{ CallInitials = "DW", Excitation = "15 V" }`, or do you want a delimited string, like `"DW|15 W", or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just `Excitation`, you could use :

```
string excitation = sensorDoc.Root.Descendants("Sensor")
            .Where(w => w.Attribute("ID").Value == sensorSN)
            .Select(w => w.Element("Amplifier").Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note That,`w => w.Element("Amplifier").Value` or `w.Element("Amplifier").Element("Excitation").Value` populate `15 V`,
and `w => w.Element("Amplifier")` populate `<Amplifier><Excitation>15 V</Excitation </Amplifier`.

If you want `DW` and `15 V`, you could use :

```
var calInitialsAndExcitation = sensorDoc.Root.Descendants("Sensor")
                .Where(w => w.Attribute("ID").Value == sensorSN)
                .Select(w => 
                new { 
                        CalInitials = w.Element("CalInitials").Value, 
                        Excitation = w.Element("Amplifier").Element("Excitation").Value
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

**UPDATE**

```
string typeGage = setupFile.Root.Descendants("Setup").Descendants("Devices")
            .Where(w => w.Element("Device").Attribute("Type").Value == "AI" 
                && w.Element("Device").Element("Slot").Attribute("Index").Value == "0")
            .Select(w => w.Element("Device").Element("Slot").Element("MeasuredValue").Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Update as per comment**

```
var typeGage = setupFile.Descendants("Device")
        .Where(d => d.Attribute("Type").Value == "AI")
        .Descendants("Slot")
        .Where(s => s.Attribute("Index").Value == "2")
        .Select(m => m.Element("OutputChannel")?.Element("MeasuredQuantity")?.Value)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: @ravens23, it's not the same XML :) i will check and i will add an answer for the update. but if you create a new question will be top.

Comment: Yeah the XML is different but the same concepts. Didnt want to ask basically the same question again. THanks!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it !

Comment: Most times I have more than one slot with all the data. It keeps coming back null for both `MeasuredValue` and `DualCore`. Do you have any idea why? Sometimes I skip from index 0 to 3 or something like that

Comment: @ravens23: share the whole xml and the code that return null values and i will check it.

Comment: @ravens23 ``OutputChannel`` and ``MeasuredQuantity`` not exist in the updated xml?

Comment: That did it! Thanks!